# How do i change Background in a Svelte Material UI (@SMUI) Slider Label?

Tags: svelte

because transparency of the slider-label and the text in the background behind of it, the label-texts are very bad to read. How can i change the transparency and the background-color of the slider-Labels?

[Transparent-Labels](https://i.stack.imgur.com/5p0tm.png)

Thank you for your answers

Comment: Hello, Can you share your code? I am unable to get the SMUI Slider to work and not seeing what versions of smui/svelte/rollup, etc will render the current slider.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

By default the `.mdc-slider .mdc-slider__value-indicator` has an opacity set to `0.6`. Just overwrite it by using:

```css
:global(.mdc-slider .mdc-slider__value-indicator) {
  opacity: 1 !important;
}
```

Checkout the example:

[image: Edit sweet-nightingale-1him4]